# How to limit the space for selected items in Jquery multi chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, multi-select, jquery-chosen

I want to limit the space of selected items space in  jquery multi chosen. Is there any way to do that?
    [image]

In multi chosen when user select more items that space gets extended. I want to limit it or add max height.

NOTE: I don't want to limit the number of selected items. I only need to limit the space there as in the image. Adding scroll bar or any solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: limit what space ?

Comment: @passion Limit the space for selected items as in the image. In multi chosen when user select more items that space gets extended. I want to limit it or add max height.

Comment: So , set the container max-height style

Comment: I tried  with max-height:75px; overflow: scroll; but not applying

Comment: Did you try to inspect the container element ? change some style to find what is it stop applying .

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Add this CSS rule to your styles.css:

```
.chosen-container .chosen-results {
    max-height:100px;
}
```